# Paypal Oauth return server error getting token in sample PizzaApp

Tags: oauth, paypal

I am trying to get the Pizza App example for the Paypal Rest API to work and I am getting a error 500 response from server

The error appears during the first call to get the Auth token.

```
 private string accessToken
    {
        get
        {
            string tokenAccess = new OAuthTokenCredential(ClientIdentity, ClientSecret).GetAccessToken();
            return tokenAccess;
        }
    }
```

The clientid and secret that are used are my own sandbox cred in the web.config. I have not modified this sample app in any way except changing creds.

Also I am using the correct endpoint as so,

```
<add name="endpoint" value="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com"/>
```

Can anyone offer some suggestions on how to narrow down the issue?

Log:2013-06-21 10:25:20,797 [7792] DEBUG PayPal.OAuthTokenCredential [(null)] grant_type=client_credentials
2013-06-21 10:25:22,622 [7792] INFO  PayPal.OAuthTokenCredential [(null)] Got InternalServerError response from server
2013-06-21 10:25:22,622 [7792] ERROR PayPal.Exception.PayPalException [(null)] The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
PayPal.Exception.PayPalException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at PayPal.OAuthTokenCredential.GenerateOAuthToken(String base64ClientID)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 1):

Sincere apologies guys - it turned out some of our SDKs (.Net and Python) weren't setting the "Content-Type" header and there was a change done on the server side of our APIs that started enforcing the "Content-Type" header as required. This was the fix done in the SDK - as noted in the change log: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I'm not sure how it slipped our standard release announcement process - we will make sure from next time all changes (they are already documented in the change logs) are also announced so everyone know when there is a new release of an SDK and the bugs fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I have had to open a support ticket for this issue. I have updated to the latest release of demo app as suggested by support and now I am getting a bad request (400) error out of the box.

Comment: The test account that we used within the app got restricted and now we have removed the restriction. If you happen to have the latest version of the SDK in the sample pizza store app, please check and confirm. We have confirmed the sample pizza app is working fine now.

Comment: Hi, I still get the 500 error when trying to make instantiate OAuthTokenCredential, I got the sdks off nuget so I assume they are the latest, is there anything else I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself on an app i'm developing. After reading this post i start wondering if they had changed something on their end, and voila, they did!
There is a new version of the SDK since Friday(21/06/2013) and access from the last SDK was cut out. Funny how they forgot to mention this to registered developers -.-

Anyway, some class names changed, the ones i found were:

- AmountDetails -> Details;
- Link -> Links.

I hope this helps, my app now works just fine =)