# Paypal API login stopped working

Tags: c#, curl, oauth-2.0, paypal

I can't login into Paypal using oauth2 to get a bearer token, getting HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error in my C# code, cUrl shows SSL error. Do I need to install any certificates on my machine and if so - where do I get them?

When I type "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2" directly in my browser the green padlock shows up, clicking on it shows the site's SSL certificate is valid.

The server and unit tests are C#, but I see an issue when making the calls with cUrl too:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token 
    -H "Accept: application/json"  
    -H "Accept-Language: en_US" 
    -u "SOMELONGB64CONTENTHERE/USER:PASSWORD"
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -v
```

this call shows an error related to SSL:

```
* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.82.78... connected
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify faile
d
* Closing connection #0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify faile
d
```

When I add the **`--insecure`** option to cUrl the call returns what's expected.

**UPDATE: ** when I run the exact same cUrl command on my Mac the response is OK and has the bearer token I expect.

The unit test code in C# (truncated error handling and logging):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:en_US"); 
string authInfo = "SOMELONGB64CONTENTHERE/USER:PASSWORD";
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

using (StreamWriter swt = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    swt.Write("grant_type=client_credentials");
}

request.BeginGetResponse((r) =>
{ 
    HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(r) as HttpWebResponse; // Exception HTTP500 here 

    // truncated code that reads the bearer token
}, null);
```

**UPDATE: ** When captured with Fiddler the raw traffic from that unit test is as follows:

Request:

```
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en_US
Authorization: Basic SOMELONGB64CONTENTHERE/USER:PASSWORD
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 29
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 118
Date: Sun, 30 Jun 2013 22:21:53 GMT
Connection: close

{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The certificate seems to be OK and valid and issued by VeriSign, expiring in 2016. Is it possible that cUrl simply can't handle it correctly?

I think your code is wrong, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx

> Your application cannot mix synchronous and asynchronous methods for a particular request. If you call the GetRequestStream method, you must use the GetResponse method to retrieve the response.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these statements helps - I'm sure Paypal's certificate is valid, a more likely possibility is that my machine lacks some root certificate. The unit test code used to work a month ago, async didn't matter; I changed it to be all sync calls but the exception remains the same

Comment: Is the exception from PayPal or your application?

Comment: It looks like Paypal is complaining about something, Fiddler shows the HTTP 500, so it's not a .NET internal error; See updates in post.

Comment: Thank you for your help (+1). Your last question pointed me to look somewhere else and I found out that Paypal broke their end and required Content Type header set.

Comment: Well glad I could be of some indirect help. :D

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was due to a breaking change in Paypal's API. Another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241975/paypal-oauth-return-server-error-getting-token-in-sample-pizzaapp) lead to Paypal's own [C# wrappers git](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/PayPalResource.cs), where around line 80 you can see the ContentType header set  to one of two values:

httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

OR

httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

The breaking change was introduced recently, the fix is from 06/20/13.